# how I can set domain on django site?

Tags: python, django

I build a django site and now want publish it on server. but dont know how I can set domain to my ip:port address.
I dont want do it with iis or cpanel or apache.
I want do it with python server.

Answer (score 0):

This is not Django related question.

What you want to do is point your domain name to the server were you host your Django application. That is usually done from Domain provider administration panel.

The only relation to Django here is that you will have to set [Allowed Hosts](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) in **Settings.py** file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
when I set domain ns in zone (windows server 2012). to access site from domain.com instead 127.0.0.1:8000 , I must just set domain.com to Allowed Hosts?!!